# Домашнее задание

Tags: морфология

Как правильно образовывать форму родительного падежа множественного числа?

Answer (score 1):

Для большей части существительных мужского рода, в начальной форме оканчивающихся на твердый согласный (*апельсин, помидор, мухомор, компьютер, носок*), характерно окончание -ов в форме родительного падежа множественного числа: *апельсинов, помидоров, мухоморов, компьютеров, носков* и т. д. Из этого правила можно выделить обширный ряд исключений - подобных существительных, но имеющих в форме родительного падежа множественного числа нулевое окончание: *один чулок — нет чулок, один осетин — пятеро осетин, один грамм — пять граммов и пять грамм* и т. п. К числу таких слов относятся:
Названия людей по национальности и по принадлежности к воинским соединениям, преимущественно употребляющиеся в формах множественного числа в собирательном значении: *мадьяры — мадьяр, туркмены — туркмен, гардемарины — гардемаринов и гардемарин, партизаны — партизан, солдаты — солдат*; сюда же относится форма р. п. мн. ч. *человек*.
Названия парных предметов: *ботинки — ботинок, глаза — глаз, манжеты - манжет, погоны — погон, чулки — чулок, эполеты — эполет, сапоги — сапог*.
Названия мер и единиц измерения: *220 вольт, 1000 ватт, 5 ампер, 500 гигабайт*. Если же такие названия употребляются вне "измерительного" контекста (иначе говоря, форма родительного падежа не является счетной), то используется окончание -*ов: жить без избыточных килограммов, не хватает гигабайтов*.

Нужно отметить, что названия плодов, фруктов и овощей, представляющие собой существительные мужского рода, в начальной форме оканчивающиеся на твердый согласный (*апельсин, баклажан, помидор, мандарин*), в форме родительного падежа мн. ч. имеют окончание -*ов: пять апельсинов, килограмм баклажанов, Новый год без мандаринов, салат из помидоров*.

Для некоторых существительных образование форм мн. ч. род. п. затруднено; это слова *мечта, мольба, башка*. Напротив, слова *щец и дровец* не имеют других форм, кроме формы мн. ч. род. падежа.

Answer (score 0):

Странный вопрос. Если вы имеете в виду конкретные слова, с которыми у вас возникли затруднения, то приведите их, и мы вам поможем. Если же вам нужна полная теория по образованию данной формы у слов каждого словоизменительного типа всех частей речи, то для этого придётся набирать несколько страниц текста. Обратитесь лучше к РГ-80 или словарю акад. Зализняка.